# Прявязка фигур друг к другу в React konva

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

Мне нужно сделать чтоб фигуры "примагничивались" друг к другу. Например взял квадрат и подвел к другому и на определнном расстояни он примагнителся к другому и важно, чтоб они образовали одну фигуру, и чтоб по кнопки их можно было обратно разъединить. Я думал чтоб отслеживать при dragMove нет ли рядом другой фигуры и магнитить одну к другой ,но как сделать не знаю.